# Drawing GL_LINE_STRIP using Pyglet in a Batch

Tags: python, opengl, pyglet

I'm trying to draw two `GL_LINE_STRIP` objects, but they become connected to eachother.

Pyglet documentation says:

> When using `GL_LINE_STRIP`, `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or `GL_QUAD_STRIP` care must be taken to insert degenerate vertices at the beginning and end of each vertex list. For example, given the vertex list:
>
> `A, B, C, D`
>
> the correct vertex list to provide the vertex list is:
>
> `A, A, B, C, D, D`

But it has absolutely no effect whether I add it or not.

Here is a code sample:

```
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

p1 = [ 300, 400, 300, 400, 162, 408, 303, 453, 300, 400, 300, 400]
p2 = [ 500, 400, 500, 400, 558, 315, 586, 372, 500, 400, 500, 400]

main_batch.add(len(p1) // 2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINE_STRIP, None, ("v2i", p1))
main_batch.add(len(p2) // 2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINE_STRIP, None, ("v2i", p2))

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    main_batch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

[image: The result]

What can I do to separate these objects? 
Using different batches or GL_LINES is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to group the vertex lists:

```py
import pyglet

window = pyglet.window.Window()

main_batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

grp1 = pyglet.graphics.Group()
grp2 = pyglet.graphics.Group()

p1 = [ 300, 400, 300, 400, 162, 408, 303, 453, 300, 400, 300, 400]
p2 = [ 500, 400, 500, 400, 558, 315, 586, 372, 500, 400, 500, 400]

main_batch.add(len(p1) // 2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINE_STRIP, grp1, ("v2i", p1))
main_batch.add(len(p2) // 2, pyglet.gl.GL_LINE_STRIP, grp2, ("v2i", p2))

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    main_batch.draw()

pyglet.app.run()
```

Vertices in 1 group are treated to be one single list of vertices. See [pyglet.graphics](https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/modules/graphics/), thus vertex lists can be add to different group. Each group is a separated mesh.

[image]

---

In my opinion the documentation is wrong. The approach will work for `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP` or `GL_QUAD_STRIP`, because this primitive types draw a filled polygon. If the area of a (part of the) polygon is 0, then nothing is drawn at all.
The line primitive `GL_LINE_STRIP` will always draw a line between to consecutive vertices.
See OpenGL [Primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive).

For instance `GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP`:

[image]

```py
p1 = [ 300, 400, 300, 400, 162, 408, 303, 453, 300, 400, 300, 400]
p2 = [ 500, 400, 500, 400, 558, 315, 586, 372, 500, 400, 500, 400]

main_batch.add(len(p1) // 2, pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, None, ("v2i", p1))
main_batch.add(len(p2) // 2, pyglet.gl.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, None, ("v2i", p2))
```